# Increasing number of rows due to Leftouter join

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have two data frames

- `df1` with 157k rows
- `df2` with 386k rows

I used left outer join to merge df2 to the df1 data frame

code I used:

```
merge = df1.join(df2, (df1.col_Mod== df2.Mod) & (df1.col_Name== df2.Name)
                 & (df1.col_age== df2.AGE), "leftouter")
```

My resultant dataframe now has **181million rows** (which is surprisingly high - it has to be 157k rows)

I could not figure out the mistake that I made. any leads would be helpful

**Note:**

Before merging the data frame. I made some changes in the df2 for proper merging.

I changed the column strings using dictionary mapping for two columns

Code:

```
nameDict = {"Alex": "ALEX", "REMY": "Remy", "Tony Lander": "Tony lander"}
df2= df2.replace(nameDict , subset=['Name']) 
modDict = {"3-ser": "3-Sirac", "premium c": "Premium", "Large C": "Large"}
df2= df2.replace(modDict, subset=['Mod'])
```

Comment: If you have duplicates in df2, join can increase rows.  You can check by `df2.dropDuplicates(['Mod', 'Name', 'Age']).count()`. Do you have 386k or less?

Comment: `df2` has an average of more than 1000 rows matching these columns for each row in `df1`. So the result gets all of these.

Comment: Can you post a [mre]? Show 10-20 rows from each table that produces this multiplication.